# What does positive_to_Qpositive_i in the QArithSternBrocot library do?

Tags: math, coq, theorem-proving

I am going through the code [`Q_denumerable.v`](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/files/QArithSternBrocot/v8.4/QArithSternBrocot.Q_denumerable.html#positive_to_Qpositive_i) in library [QArithSternBrocot](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/view/QArithSternBrocot/v8.4) and this is what I came across.

```
Fixpoint positive_to_Qpositive_i (p:positive) : Qpositive := 
   match p with 
   | xI p => nR (positive_to_Qpositive_i p)
   | xO p => dL (positive_to_Qpositive_i p)
   | xH => One
   end.
```

What do `nR` and `dL` mean?

Answer (score 2):

The library name and the documentation refers to the [Stern-Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree), but in fact the encoding is a variant of it called [Calkin-Wilf tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree). `One` is the root of the tree, which is the number 1, and the constructors `nR` and `dL` indicate the two children: if `w` represents p/q (with p and q coprime, i.e. the rational is in irreducible form) then `nR w` represents ((p+q)/q) and `dL w` represents (p/(p+q)). The function [`Qpositive_i`](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/files/QArithSternBrocot/v8.4/QArithSternBrocot.Qpositive.html#Qpositive_i) calculates the (numerator, denominator) representation of a `Qpositive` value.

The function [`positive_to_Qpositive_i`](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/files/QArithSternBrocot/v8.4/QArithSternBrocot.Q_denumerable.html#positive_to_Qpositive_i) calculates the Calkin-Wilf representation of a positive integer given in binary notation.

Answer (score 1):

`nR` and `nL` are constructors of the `Qpositive` type, whose [definition](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/files/QArithSternBrocot/v8.4/QArithSternBrocot.Qpositive.html) is:

```
Inductive Qpositive : Set :=
  | nR : Qpositive → Qpositive
  | dL : Qpositive → Qpositive
  | One : Qpositive.
```

From what I could understand, the idea is that, if some `x : Qpositive` represents a positive rational number `p / q`, then `dL x` represents `p / (p + q)`, whereas `nR x` represents `(p + q) / q`. You can have a look e.g. at the [`Qpositive_i`](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/files/QArithSternBrocot/v8.4/QArithSternBrocot.Qpositive.html#Qpositive_i) function: for each `x : Qpositive`, it gives you the natural numbers `p` and `q` such that `x` represents `p / q`.

It's not too hard to figure out how to represent a given positive rational number in this notation (it's what the `Qpositive_c` function in that same file seems to be doing). For instance, here's how you represent `5 / 8` (in informal Coq-like syntax):

```
5 / 8
= 5 / (5 + 3) = dL (5 / 3)
= dL ((2 + 3) / 3) = dL (nR (2 / 3))
= dL (nR (2 / (2 + 1))) = dL (nR (dL (2 / 1)))
= dL (nR (dL ((1 + 1) / 1))) = dL (nR (dL (nR (1 / 1))))
= dL (nR (dL (nR One)))
```

Hence, the `positive_to_Qpositive_i` function, as its name suggests, is an isomorphism between the `positive` and `Qpositive` types. Both types have essentially the same set of constructors, but with different names, so that the function only needs to translate between the two declarations.